# How to make a windows form to move when long clicked C#

Tags: c#, mouseevent, move

I have a windows form in C#, it looks like a lonely button, even without the "X" top bar. I made it to be only a button, and I want that when I touch the button a long touch, I will be able to move it on my screen.

I succeed to make that when I touch the windows form background I can move it, but I want it to happen when I touch the *button*.

After a look on the internet, I made this code, but I have no idea what to write on the moveApp() mehtod.

This is my code:

```
namespace Print_My_Screen
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();       
       }

       private void PrintScreen()
       {

         Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

         Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

         graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

         string subPath = @"C:\PrintMyScreen";
         bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(subPath);

         if (!exists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);

         printscreen.Save(@"C:\PrintMyScreen\printscreen.png", ImageFormat.Png);
         printIt();

         MessageBox.Show("Your screen has been printed successfully","",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         PrintScreen();
      }

      private void printIt()
      {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        // pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\PrintMyScreen\printscreen.png");
            img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
            args.Graphics.DrawImage(img, args.MarginBounds);
        };

        pd.Print();
      }

      private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
      {
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\PrintMyScreen\printscreen.png");
        Point loc = new Point(100, 100);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
        img.Dispose();
      }
      protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
      {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x84:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if ((int)m.Result == 0x1)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)0x2;
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
      }

      private void moveApp()
      {

      }

      public void Repeater(Button btn, int interval)
      {
        var timer = new Timer { Interval = interval };
        timer.Tick += (sender, e) => moveApp();
        btn.MouseDown += (sender, e) => timer.Start();
        btn.MouseUp += (sender, e) => timer.Stop();
        btn.Disposed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
        };
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing a lot.

In order to move your form, you need to send windows a message that the left button is down on the caption of the form.
This can be achieved with the following:

```
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
```

Then use it in your `moveapp`:

```
  private void moveApp()
  {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
  }
```

One more thing, since you are using the `Windows.Forms.Timer` in your `Repeater`, you will enter the `moveapp` every *`interval`* miliseconds.
You have to `Stop` it in order to enter just once.
So, The `Repeater` now looks like this:

```
  public void Repeater(Button btn, int interval)
  {
    var timer = new Timer { Interval = interval };
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>  {timer.Stop();moveApp();}
    btn.MouseDown += (sender, e) => timer.Start();
    btn.MouseUp += (sender, e) => timer.Stop();
    btn.Disposed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    };
  }
```

*Don't forget to call the repeater in your constructor... I don't see you do it.*